# how find regular expression pattern for a number which have a white space in between using java

Tags: java, regex

This the regex that i want to match

> 5 9 5 4  1 9 9 2 2  1 4 7 3 there is a single space in between every number and a double number in between the for digit and the five digit number .

this is how i tried to solve it

```
    ([0-9\\s]|[0-9]){4}[\\s]([0-9\\s]|[0-9]){5}[\\s]([0-9\\s]|[0-9]){4}
```

Can anybody tell me what did i miss here?

Comment: Please don't post text as an image but as text so everyone can easily copy it. Provide sample inputs and your expected outputs. Show the context you are using the regex in. At the moment this question is unclear.

Comment: now i edited my question hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

### Suggested regex

The regex

```
((?:\d\s*)*)
```

should do the trick, it finds as many single digit numbers separated by any number of whitespace as possible.

### Breaking down your regex for explanation

Looking at the different parts of

```
([0-9\\s]|[0-9]){4}[\\s]([0-9\\s]|[0-9]){5}[\\s]([0-9\\s]|[0-9]){4}
```

**Firstly:** `([0-9\\s]|[0-9]){4}`
is equivalent to `[0-9\\s]{4}`, that is: any number between 0 and 9 **or** a whitespace **exactly** 4 times. This would match the first 4 characters of your string (2 numbers and 2 spaces).

**Secondly:** `[\\s]`is equivalent to `\\s` directly as "any character in \s" is equal to "\s".

The rest of your regex follows the same structure.

### Suggested fixes

I would suggest cleaning up the regex therefore as:

```
[0-9\s]{4}\s[0-9\s]{5}\s[0-9\s]{4}
```

although I expect what you meant to write was:

```
(?:[0-9]\s?){4}\s(?:[0-9]\s?){5}\s(?:[0-9]\s?){4}
```

which will match (in order):

1. 4 digits separated by one or no whitespaces
2. 1 whitespace
3. 5 digits separated by one or no whitespaces
4. 1 whitespace
5. 4 digits separated by one or no whitespaces

But I think you're better off with my regex above as it is more flexible for finding digit combinations separated by any number of whitespace.

### Conclusion

I think your mistake was a confusion of `[]` and `()`. `[]` will match any character inside, `()` will match all characters in the order specified.

Also the quantifier `?` means 1 or 0 and is quicker/clearer to use than an `or` operator.